# WP7 app won't launch from app list

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a simple Windows Phone 7 application which is working perfectly when started from Visual Studio. However, if I deactivate the app (press Windows button or back button from the application's MainPage) and then click the app's icon to relaunch, the screen will flash and return to the list/home screen. I assumed this was an issue with the emulator but when I got a developer device I have the same issue.

Note that reactivating without a complete tombstone works (pressing Windows button from the app and then back).

I have no idea what causes this or how to proceed with debugging. Hopefully someone else has experienced this and knows a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there is a bug, i found the solution here http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/67522/416995.aspx

In short, it turns out that the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary class (which I am using to display pictures on applications main page) is not properly initialized when the user has not opened a media hub prior to you calling it. So picture collection properties are null or empty. The solution is to add a call to MediaPlayer.Queue.ToString(), it will force the initialization of the native media library allowing you to invoke the MediaLibrary later on.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an unhandled error on startup is causing the app to crash.

Trap/log/handle/display any unhandled exceptions. Also check what you're doing on startup.

IF you are saving something (to Isolated Storage) after first run and then opening it on subsequent launches then that's where I'd look first.

If it works when launched from Visual Studio then this will probably be due to the way you are rebuilding/redeploying the app before launching it in that case.